# what can use listener for load complete page map.html so do work with JavaScript on map.html

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

if i have index.html and a button go to map.html, what can use listener for load complete page map.html so do work with JavaScript on map.html?

Comment: You need to be more specific, page loaded into DOM or page loaded and shown?

Answer (score 0):

If you use plain javascript, you can rely on "load" event.

If you use jQuery, you can rely on ready event.

Comment: well i found for ready device done for index.html and then linked to secondary page(eg map.html) call the below... required both statements?                                               // This gets called by jQuery mobile when the page has loaded                              
$(document).bind("pageload", function(event, data) {
init(data.url);
});                                                                
// Set an onload handler to call the init function
window.onload = init;

Answer (score 0):

```
// This gets called by jQuery mobile when the page has loaded 

$(document).bind("pageload", function(event, data) { init(data.url); }); 



// Set an onload handler to call the init function 
window.onload = init;
```

Comment: $(document).bind("pageload", onMapLoad);

Comment: well i found for ready device done for index.html and then linked to secondary page(eg map.html) call the below... required both statements? // This gets called by jQuery mobile when the page has loaded $(document).bind("pageload", function(event, data) { init(data.url); }); // Set an onload handler to call the init function window.onload = init;